# Altering foreign key name

Tags: mysql

If you alter the name of a foreign key will the foreign key still be "connected" with its primary key and how do I check to make sure? Sorry if this is a simple question but I just want to be sure and I couldn't find a resource to give me an answer.

Comment: constraints can only be dropped and re-attached in `MYSQL`

Comment: This seems to belong on [dba.stackexchange.com/](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) (*Database Administrators Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community.*) instead, as it has nothing to do with programming.